# $n\times n$ matrix where $\alpha$ is an eigenvalue of $A$

Tags: linear-algebra

Question:Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. Let A be an $n \times n$ matrix such that the sum of the entries in each column of A is $\alpha$. Prove that $\alpha$ is an eigenvalue of A.

Proof:Suppose A has the property that for each of its rows, the sum of the entries in that row is the same number as $\alpha$. For example if

$A= \begin{pmatrix} 4&-1&-1\\ 0&1&1\\ 2&0&0 \end{pmatrix}$

The row sums of A are all equal to 2. Then

$A \begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 1\\ \cdots \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} \alpha\\ \alpha \\ \cdots\\ \alpha \end{pmatrix} = \alpha \begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 1\\ \cdots \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$

Thus the vector whose entries are all equal to $1$ is an eigenvector of A corresponding to the eigenvalue $\alpha$. In particular the common row sum $\alpha$ is an eigenvalue of A.

Would this be correct?

Comment: In general it is bad practice to use the phrase "for example" in a proof.

Also, the question states that $A$ is a square matrix such that "the sum of the entries in each *column* of $A$ is $\alpha$". Your proof seems to make the assumption that the sum of all the entries in each row of $A$ is $\alpha$.

Comment: Ok so what your saying is that my answer doesn't really answer the question

Comment: Yes, but it's still a good idea! My answer gives a hint.

Answer (score 4):

The assumption in this question is that the sum of all the entries in each column of $A$ is $\alpha$. This means that $A^\top(e_1+\dotsb+e_n)=\alpha(e_1+\dotsb+e_n)$. This shows that $\alpha$ is an eigenvalue of $A^\top$. How are the eigenvalues of $A$ and $A^\top$ related?

Comment: They have the same eigenvalues?

Comment: @RuthGutierrez Correct! Can you prove it?

Comment: well could I show that how I had stated it before where the eigenvector of A is corresponding $\alpha$

Comment: @RuthGutierrez I don't think so. Try using the formula $\det(A-\lambda I)=\det\left((A-\lambda I)^\top\right)=\det\left(A^\top-(\lambda I)^\top\right)=\det\left(A^\top-\lambda \left(I^\top\right)\right)=\det\left(A^\top-\lambda I\right)$

Comment: So bascially I need to show that the $det(A^T)= det(A)$

Comment: @RuthGutierrez Yes, but this is a pretty standard result proved in most linear algebra courses.

Comment: So because they equal each other then that proves $\alpha$ is an eigenvalue of A?

Comment: Well, the point is not that $\det(A)=\det(A^\top)$. The point is that you can prove that $A$ and $A^\top$ have the same *characteristic polynomial*.